# Lucene OR query with condition

Tags: lucene

I set default operator as QueryParser.Operator.AND and want to run query (on 2 fields)

```
(apple OR windows) AND source:(40 OR 41)
```

but that's what Lucene is doing

```
(windows) AND source:(40 OR 41)
```

Why it runs that way and how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

More code and what do I mean by 2 fields

```
        QueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(CURRENT_LUCENE_VERSION,
                new String[]{Config.TITLE_FIELD, Config.DESCRIPTION_FIELD}, getAnalyzer());
            parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
            query = parser.parse(QueryParser.escape(searchString));
            collector = TopFieldCollector.create(new Sort(
                new SortField(Config.TIME_FIELD, SortField.LONG, true)),
                Math.max(lastDoc, 1), true, true, true, true);
            Filter fl = new TermRangeFilter(Config.TIME_FIELD,
                "" + crit.getFilter().getStartDate().getTime(),
                "" + crit.getFilter().getEndDate().getTime(), true, true);
            indexSearcher.search(query, fl, collector);
```

## --------------------------------------------------

I cant use

```
+(content:apple content:windows) +(source:40 source:41)
```

because I have to search by 2 fields

## --------------------------------------------------

How do you get what Lucene is doing?

I get it by comparing results. Here what I got by doing toString()

```
(title:apple content:apple) +(title:windows content:windows) +(source:40 source:41)
```

How to remove plus from second expression?

Comment: please share more information about your code, please, particularly im interested in what do you mean by saying on 2 fields?

Comment: How do you get what Lucene is doing? Do you call `toString()` on the parsed query or do you infer this from the search results?

Comment: Running your query through the standard QueryParser with the default operator set, I get:  `+(content:apple content:windows) +(source:40 source:41)`, which looks right to me.  Probably going to need to provide more information.